# Rails 3 replaces & with &amp; in text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-escape-characters

I'm using Rails 3. When a user submits a form with a text_field and has & entered in it, the form gets validated. When it isn't valid, Rails returns an error, which I then show to the user. But now the & is translated to `&amp;` . How can I change this behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: You want to un-escape the HTML in the error message?  That's probably not wise, XSS attacks being what they are.  Why would you want to show non-escaped HTML as HTML?

Comment: It is not in the error message.

For example a user enters `'Company & Sons'` as his company name. When he submits the form and gets an error, the text field with his company name then reads `'Company &amp; Sons'`. That is not right, is it?

Comment: Ah, that's different.  You are correct, the form contents should not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the culprit. I was sending my input to a sanitizer method, which replaced all ampersands by `&amp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try "risky string".html_safe